# Mocking an asyc function in react using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking

I am new to react and jest.
I am getting stuck on the right way to mock an async function even after scouring many articles on this.
here is my scenario. I am pasting the code which is giving me trouble. I have the following function defined. I want to mock the getToken() function. The returned token is a string.

```
export async getSignin() {
   const token = await getToken()
   //do something with this token
}

    

export async function getToken(){
    const token =  (await accessToken())
    return token
}

Test code:
it(" returns a valid user ", async () => {
   const getToken = jest
            .fn()
            .mockImplementation(async () => Promise.resolve("abcd"))
   const signedin = await getSignin()
}
```

when I do this, my expectation is that the code will use the mock implementation of the getToken and proceed. What I am getting is that it is throwing an error at accessToken(). My understanding of mock is that it should not go into the actual implementation and call accessToken()

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem, don't truncate things if you're not sure it's safe. Here the most important thing is that whether getSignin and getToken are in the same module. If they are, you cannot mock getToken.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch-mock` is a great package for mocking API requests in your test files! http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock

After installing, in your `beforeEach` block in a test file you can now mock the payload from API calls. It will look something like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
   fetchMock.mock('/api/users'/1, { id: 1, name: 'Test User Name', address: 'Test User Address'})
})
```

Comment: fetch -mock helps with only fetch requests, right?

Comment: It will work with fetch, yes. If you are using axios, you can use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios